# Package NLog 3.2.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0)

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core-rc2

Here is the project.json file.

```
{
 "dependencies": {
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
  "version": "1.0.0-rc2-3002702",
  "type": "platform"
},
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Swashbuckle": "6.0.0-beta9",
"Swashbuckle.SwaggerGen": "6.0.0-beta9",
"Swashbuckle.SwaggerUi": "6.0.0-beta9",
"EasyGelf.NLog": "0.4.5.57"
},

"tools": {
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
  "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
 }
},

"frameworks": {
"netcoreapp1.0": {
  "imports": [
    "dotnet5.6",
    "dnxcore50",
    "portable-net45+win8"
   ]
 }
},

"buildOptions": {
"emitEntryPoint": true,
"preserveCompilationContext": true
},
```

The error is

```
Package NLog 3.2.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package NLog 3.2.0 supports:
  - net35 (.NETFramework,Version=v3.5)
  - net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
  - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
  - sl4 (Silverlight,Version=v4.0)
  - sl5 (Silverlight,Version=v5.0)
One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
```

Comment: At this stage, far too many NuGet packages are not yet .NET Core compatible. You will have to wait, or send pull requests to help them out.

Answer (score 0):

You have added EasyGelf.Nlog, that does not support .NET CORE: https://github.com/Pliner/EasyGelf/blob/master/Source/EasyGelf.NLog/packages.config

Answer (score 0):

While you're only indirectly adding NLog, NLog does support .NET Core if you use the beta package

https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog/4.4.0-betaV14